# Import API to execute an Update IMPEX programmatically

Tags: api, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

Is it possible to use the Import API to execute an Update Impex programmatically? Currently I must log into HAC and execute an update Impex using the web interface which is tedious.

Answer (score 2):

The **DefaultImportService** has a method called **importData**. This method needs an **ImportConfig** object as a parameter.

In this **ImportConfig** you can set the way you want to run your Impex(like in hac, for example you can choose to run the impex in legacy mode) and you can set the script that will be run also(i.e **setScript(ImpExResource script)**).